# How do I fix a dishwasher leak and repair damage to surrounding cabinets?

Tags: appliances, mold, dishwasher

I have a Whirlpool dishwasher bought in 2005 that evidently leaks steam from the side and has caused mold to build up on the cabinet door that is next to it.  What could cause this to happen and how do we fix it?  This is a rental property so I am not sure how long this has been happening and do not have the manual that came with the dishwasher.  The tenants were not very clean people and have left a mess in the house, and took all the manuals.  Of course, they never let us know this happened.  The cabinets, also new in 2005 and bought at Lowes,  have the painted covers to start popping off.  If you have an idea how that can be fixed or if they can be painted, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Is the dishwasher leaking steam at the seal between the door and the body of the dishwasher? If so, the door seal probably needs replacing. What to do about the mold and the cabinets depend on how bad they are - pictures are always helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If the dishwasher itself is leaking from a crack in the side of the tub, then it cannot be repaired and needs to be replaced. If it's just leaking from the door, then there's a door seal that can be replaced. You'll have to contact Whirlpool or an appliance repair guy for that -- appliance repair is something that we don't really cover around here because it's not really a DIY thing.

It sounds like the cabinets had a veneer that was then painted. You should be able to glue the veneer back down with some construction adhesive or epoxy. Unfortunately, many of the cabinets that Lowe's sells these days are made from particle board, and the cabinet itself might need some repair or shoring up before it can be used again. We can advise you more if you post some pictures.

I hope they didn't get any of their deposit back!

Answer (score 0):

if its an apt.  the landlord is responsible for the repair, unless your lease says you get to fix everything, your not the owner of the dishwasher im assuming because its an apt. the owner /landlord is responsible for it. if there is only one cabinet side that is moldy it has to be sanded down untill its completly gone and then amonia rubbed on it to kill all spores. again the landlord is responsible even if you caused this to happen its there equipment. if its alot of mold then you must tell the landlord he needs to have a mold inspector look at it to determine the type of mold, and to rid of all mold. 
   im assuming the steam is coming from underneath the unit in a drain hose or supply hose and should be easily repaired by a competent appliance person. 
most mold is harmless found in a home but it could be bad stuff i would demand the landlord have an inspector take a look.
good luck

Comment: Read the question; the OP **is** the landlord.